# Find Wingdings character (Powerpoint 2013+)

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I'm looking for a way to programatically find a special Wingdings character on a slide.

[image]

e.g. the Wingdings character with a decimal code of 254.

However since it seems to be easy to do in Word (see here: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/FindReplaceSymbols.htm) I can't figure out a way to do it in Powerpoint.

Word provides a function that gets name and the char code of a symbol

```
Sub GetCharNoAndFont()

With Dialogs(wdDialogInsertSymbol)
    Debug.Print "Font: " & .Font
    Debug.Print "Char number " & .CharNum
End With

End Sub
```

Is there any equivalent in Powerpoint?

Comment: Does it *need* to be done programmarcally?

Comment: Here, you can have some of mine; I've got plenty: ✘ ☒ ✓ ☑ ✘ ☒ ✓ ☑ ✘ ☒ ✓ ☑ ✘ ☒ ✓ ☑

Comment: well yes. I want to be able to identify any characters that are not e.g. Arial. I wrote a function for shapes, tables, groups, bullet points etc. but symbols are pretty tricky since a textfield with a symbol inside does not show the font of that symbol

Comment: oh, you want to identify the code for each symbol?

Comment: yes somewhat. I need the code to search for the symbols in the second step

Answer (score 0):

I might still misunderstand your question (I'm not sure what you mean by `search for symbols`) but you could use:

---

### Powerpoint:

- [**`TextRange.InsertSymbol` Method** (PowerPoint)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/textrange-insertsymbol-method-powerpoint)
- [**`AscW` Function** (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/asc-function)
- [**`ChrW` Function** (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/asc-function)
- **[Insert ASCII or Unicode Latin-based symbols and characters](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0)** (Office 2007-2016)

---

### Excel:

- **[`WorksheetFunction.Unicode Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-unicode-method-excel)** to identify the code for a Unicode character.
- **[`WorksheetFunction.Unichar Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-unichar-method-excel)** to return (display) a Unicode character.
- **[`WorksheetFunction.Find Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-find-method-excel)** to find specific symbols on a worksheet.

Comment: PowerPoint doesn't have worksheet functions, though.

Comment: I had had a go at this. As far as I could see  ChrW fails, the code returned for ASC I think was 63? Anyway, was for the ? not the tick. You can't identify the font as windings.  Yes, you can iterate by character over the TextRange and use those functions but I still couldn't get one that correctly identified a check mark :-( I was very frustrated.

Comment: what @QHarr said is exactly the problem!

Comment: It is a limitation of the object model. You could hack your way by detecting existence of a symbol character using the approach described by Qharr and then copy it to be the clipboard to parse the information and get the font or take a cleaner approach by using OpenXml to detect symbols and get the font information.